# Excel VBA code For opening Excel xlsx File on a daily Basis with date in his name

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 files that I want to merge to one report. Both files are in different folders and they are alone in their folder.

My problem is that when I dim each workbook as a variable I need to put a path with the name of the file.
I want that the path will stay and every time I run the Macro it will dim the current workbook in the file as "x"

Name of file for example - Clean room GSS parts - tracking file 17.05.2017

Here is my code:

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\GSS\Clean room GSS parts - tracking file 17.05.2017.xlsx")
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can do: `Const filePath = C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\GSS\` and 'Dim fileNameX As String`, and then combine both together to a new source/target file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the date of a cell, input or `NOW` to a string with the format you use in the filename:

```
FORMAT(NOW(),"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

Now you can use this when opening the file:

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\GSS\Clean room GSS parts - tracking file " & FORMAT(NOW(),"dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx")
```

---

Remember that you can use other values than the current date `NOW()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps, ask the user to select the file that you are wanting to select using the File Dialog Box.

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum FileDialogType
    msoFileDialogOpen = 1
    msoFileDialogSaveAs = 2
    msoFileDialogFilePicker = 3
    msoFileDialogFolderPicker = 4
End Enum

Public Function OpenTargetWBExample()
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker, "Select workbook to open")
    If Len(FilePath) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim TargetWB As Workbook: Set TargetWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    'Extra code goes here
    Set TargetWB = Nothing
End Function

Public Function FileDialog(ByVal DialogType As FileDialogType, Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String, _
                              Optional MultiSelect As Boolean, Optional ByVal FileFilter As String) As String
    'If MultiSelect then outputs files in the following format: "File1;File2;File3"
    'Custom File Extension Filter Format: "File Description 1~File Extension Filter 1|File Description 2~File Extension Filter 2"
    Dim FileDialogObject As FileDialog: Set FileDialogObject = Application.FileDialog(DialogType)
    Dim Index As Long, Filters() As String, Element() As String
    Dim SelectedFile As Variant

    With FileDialogObject
        If Len(DialogTitle) > 0 Then .Title = DialogTitle
        .AllowMultiSelect = MultiSelect
        If Len(FileFilter) > 0 Then
            Filters = Split(FileFilter, "|")
            For Index = 0 To UBound(Filters)
                Element = Split(Filters(Index), "~")
                .Filters.Add Element(0), Element(1), (.Filters.Count + 1)
            Next Index
        End If
        .FilterIndex = 0
        .Show
        .Filters.Clear
        For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems
            FileDialog = FileDialog & CStr(SelectedFile) & ";"
        Next SelectedFile
        If Len(FileDialog) > 0 Then FileDialog = Left(FileDialog, Len(FileDialog) - 1)
    End With
    Set FileDialogObject = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

since there is only one file in the directory

```
dim aaa as String
aaa = ""C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\GSS\"

Set x = Workbooks.Open(aaa & Dir(aaa))
```